# Can I get VBA to show a confirmation msgbox when a cell is changed, that "undoes" the change if the user selects "no"

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a tracker for my credit hours at work using Excel with dates running horizontally across row D, with rows E and F each tracking hours earned and hours spent respectively below each date.

I already have code that checks to see if the user selects a cell that is past the current date, and this raises a confirmation msgbox saying "this date is in the future, are you sure you want to continue?"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myDate As Variant, rng As Range

    On Error GoTo ws_exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C5:CZO5")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) > Date Then
        With Target
            If MsgBox("Caution: You are about to modify a future date, are you sure you want to do this?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Modification Warning") = vbNo Then
                Set rng = Range("C4:CZO4")
                Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
                Cells(myDate.Row, myDate.Column).Select
                Set rng = Nothing
            End If
        End With

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C6:CZO6")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0) > Date Then
        With Target
            If MsgBox("Caution: You are about to modify a future date, are you sure you want to do this?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Modification Warning") = vbNo Then
                Set rng = Range("C4:CZO4")
                Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
                Cells(myDate.Row, myDate.Column).Select
                Set rng = Nothing
            End If
        End With
    End If

ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works fine, although I now want to create a separate msgbox that will ask the user to confirm that they have authorisation from their line manager once they edit the value of a cell. If the user selects "no", I want the code to undo the last change (i.e., changing the value of the cell).
Is this possible?
The code that I have so far will bring up the msgbox but pressing "no" doesn't undo the value change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:CZO6")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If MsgBox("Caution: Ensure line manager's permission is granted, do you want to continue?", vbCaution + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Authourisation Reminder") = vbNo Then
                Set rng = Range("C4:CZO4")
                Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
                Cells(myDate.Row, myDate.Column).Select
                Set rng = Nothing
            End If
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated as usual! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use Application.Undo

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:CZO6")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If MsgBox("Caution: Ensure line manager's permission is granted, do you want to continue?", vbCaution + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Authourisation Reminder") = vbNo Then
Application.Undo ' this should do the trick
                Set rng = Range("C4:CZO4")
                Set myDate = rng.Find(What:=Int(Date), LookIn:=xlValues)
                Cells(myDate.Row, myDate.Column).Select
                Set rng = Nothing
            End If
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```